# Contents of Block Layout Change Position on Zoom

Tags: sapui5

I need to fit a `Label` and a `Hbox` within [block layout](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.BlockLayout).

```xml
<l:BlockLayout id="BlockLayout">
  <l:BlockLayoutRow>
    <l:BlockLayoutCell width="100%">
      <Label
        class="sapUiTinyMargin" 
        text="Hello All"
      >
      <Hbox>
      </Hbox>
    </l:BlockLayoutCell>
  </l:BlockLayoutRow>
</l:BlockLayout>
```

Every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in or out, the block layout contents change their position. E.g.: Label shifts right on zoom out and in on zoom in.

What should I do to stop this?

Comment: Does this problem occur on a small screen, like a small mobile device?
The [official SAP docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.BlockLayout/overview) might be helpful:
Here it says:
Usage
- When to use
You want to create a catalogue-like page with sections of blocks.
The BlockLayout is intended for developing administrative tools and applications.
- When not to use
You want to display properties or features of one content item. Use a object page or dynamic page instead.

Comment: - Responsive Behavior
The breakpoints of the block layout react to the width of the control itself and not to the actual screen size.
On small screens all blocks will wrap to a single scrollable column

Do you have the same issues with the samples from [the official SAP docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.BlockLayout) ?

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice. I was working on laptop with around 13 inch screen. Surprisingly only block layout was changing position. Other layouts like grid, stayed firm. I will definitely follow the document links you shared. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: BlockLayout is a responsive UI5 element. It is like a flexbox, and it will always try to adjust its elements to "optimize" (so it thinks) the space it has.

I am not fully aware of what you really want to do, but my advice will be to not use BlockLayout and try to place manually (css) your elements (since it looks you don't like the responsiveness of the elements...

Some properties like: justifyContent="SpaceBetween" justifyContent="SpaceArround" alignItems="Center".
Might be useful to you, I'm not sure.